# {% block page_content %} for flask template - docs

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2, template-engine

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}  
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This works fine, however I am wondering where i can see the documentation for `page_content` block. i can't find any reference in available [blocks](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#available-blocks) for flask Bootstrap.

What defines `page_content`? Flask-Bootstrap or Jinja2?

Answer (score 2):

Jinja2 does not define anything. It is just the framework.

I don't know which version of `Flask-Bootstrap` you are using, but I'm sure `page_content` is from it or from a dependency of it.

`Flask-Bootstrap` docs define the available blocks.

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#available-blocks

Of course you can check their templates and override anything else there, but I didn't found the `page_content` in their code. Maybe it is from an older version.

https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=page_content

Comment: the only information about page_content that I found is present in this book https://books.google.pt/books?id=5aNwAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&lpg=PT56&dq=page_content+derived&source=bl&ots=DStBRCPKJt&sig=UcAWMgleK2PN6Fjzn-p0fcosiLw&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMI48XapfriyAIVgbYUCh0HHAwu

Answer (score 1):

Hope this clarifies the confusion.

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}  
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

From your code note that {% block content %} is a Flask-Bootstrap's actually base template block. Blocks defined between {% block content %} and {% endblock %} can be named anything. The idea is that you can add new blocks (name them anything you want) but they must be defined inside a block that already exists in a parent template, and {% block content % } does exist in "bootstrap/base.html".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's a user defined symbol, you can test this with changing both "base.html" and "derived.html"'s `{% block page_content %}` to `{% block abcde %}`, it also works, so I think it's a section reference.